# comparing databases and generating sql script using liquibase

Tags: ant, liquibase

I'm comparing two databases using liquibase integrated with ant. But the output it is generating is like generic format. It is not giving sql statements. Please can anyone tell me how compare two databases using liquibase integrated with ant or command line utility.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Obtaining the SQL statements, representing the diff between two databases, is a two step operation:

1. Generate the XML "diff" changelog
2. Generate SQL statements

## Example

This example requires a **liquibase.properties** file (simplifies the [command-line](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/command_line) parameters):

```
classpath=/path/to/jdbc/jdbc.jar
driver=org.Driver
url=jdbc:db_url1
username=user1
password=pass1
referenceUrl=jdbc:db_url2
referenceUsername=user2
referencePassword=pass2
changeLogFile=diff.xml
```

Now run the following commands to create the SQL statements:

```sh
liquibase diffChangeLog
liquibase updateSQL > update.sql
```

A nice feature of liquibase is that it can also generate the rollback SQL:

```sh
liquibase futureRollbackSQL > rollback.sql
```

## Update

Liquibase does not generate a data diff between databases, only the schema. However, it is possible to dump database data as a series of changesets:

```sh
liquibase --changeLogFile=data.xml --diffTypes=data generateChangeLog
```

One can use the **data.xml** file to migrate data contained in new tables.

## Update 2:

Also possible to generate liquibase changesets using groovy.

```java
import groovy.sql.Sql 
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

//
// DB connection
//
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new URL("file:///home/path/to/h2-1.3.162.jar"))
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:h2:db/db1","user","pass","org.h2.Driver")

//
// Generate liquibase changeset
//
def author = "generated"
def id = 1

new File("extract.xml").withWriter { writer ->
    def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer);

    xml.databaseChangeLog(
        "xmlns":"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog",
        "xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        "xsi:schemaLocation":"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd"
    ) {
        changeSet(author:author, id:id++) {
            sql.eachRow("select * from employee") { row ->
                insert(tableName:"exmployee") {
                    column(name:"empno",    valueNumeric:row.empno)
                    column(name:"name",     value:row.name)
                    column(name:"job",      value:row.job)
                    column(name:"hiredate", value:row.hiredate)
                    column(name:"salary",   valueNumeric:row.salary)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hiee I'm able to see the diff but if a table is missing it will just create the table , but wont copy the table data from source db to target db. Is there any solution for that

Comment: No not a complete solution. I've update my answer to indicate how the data can be dumped as a series of changesets. This generated data can be used to load new tables in the the new database.

Comment: hiee after executing the command it gives java heap space error. I tried setting java heap size as %JAVA_OPTS% -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m. Can u plz help me in this?

Comment: I think your dataset is too large. Try generating the changeset (updated my answer) or perhaps just use a normal database data loading tool.