# How can I use node-pg-migrate with independent lanes of migrations?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-migration

Currently, migration scripts ([node-pg-migrate](https://github.com/salsita/node-pg-migrate)) build the entire database from zero to everything. It's the database of a new system that is going to replace the legacy system. Data needs to be imported from the legacy system to the new database. They have completely different data structures.

The migrations scripts build the `import` schema with raw data imported from the legacy system (using its web service). Then all other schemas with its tables, functions and everything is created. Primarily the `data` schema with data transformed from the `import` schema usable for the new system. The `api` schema with views and functions exposed through postgREST working on data from the `data` schema. And some more helper schemas and stuff.

Now, the data to be imported is not final yet, so I need to re-import often. To do that, I need to migrate all the way down, dropping all other schemas as it goes down to get to the migration steps that remove all imported data and drops the `import` schema. Then go up again to import the data all the way up again to build all the schemas to have a working api again.

I'm getting to my question now shortly... I'm quite sure I need to move the import data scripts away from the migration so I don't need to deconstruct and reconstruct the entire database and all its schemas. Ideally, I want to run import scripts and schema scripts independently. Using `node-pg-migrate` though is really convenient, also for importing the data.

How can I use node-pg-migrate with independent lanes of migrations? One for imports (or dml changes) and one for schema changes (or ddl changes).

*Related:*

- [Migration scripts for Structure and Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809509/migration-scripts-for-structure-and-data)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64632/how-to-create-a-versioning-ddl-dml-change-script-for-sql-server

*Update: I just found out the solution may lie in the area of [scope](https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting%20Started/commands/#scoping) as implemented by node-db-migrate*. I'm using [node-pg-migrate](https://github.com/salsita/node-pg-migrate) though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node-pg-migrate` does not support lanes as e.g. `db-migrate`. But you can emulate them IMO in a way, that you will use separate migrations folder and table:

`node-pg-migrate -m migrations/dll -t pgmigrations_dll`

`node-pg-migrate -m migrations/dml -t pgmigrations_dml`