# How to automate deployment of entity model changes to database?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, entity-framework, deployment, continuous-integration

Currently I use Visual Studio Database Project, so I can deploy changes to database with one click and keep data in database.

Now I want to be able to create model in Entity Framework and deploy with one click.

So I got sql script to create database from Entity Framework. I can run this script to create database, but I want to keep my data in database.

Is there any way to do that ? Any tool that will do that ? Should I generate it on my own with T4 ?

I use CI so I need to be able to deploy often. I want something similar to Visual Studio Database Project deployment, but with Entity Framework generated database.

Comment: @ Arran : In this case I use Visual Studio

Comment: Have you considered generating your model from your database?  You would still be able to deploy your database as you do now, and would be able to update your model with a couple of clicks

Comment: @ dskh : I want sql from model and not model from sql. I want to edit model. The thing that You are talking about is the thing I have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to generate Visual Studio Database Project from Entity Framework Model You need to install **Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack**.

You need to add Database Project to Your solution and then create edmx model **with the same name**. Then right click on edmx workspace and select **Generate Database from Model** and from generation menu **Sync Database Project**.

You can then deploy this Sql project from Visual Studio to Sql Server.

Answer (score 2):

[Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) is a database change management tool. It's implemented in Java but a command-line version is available to control your database upgrades (.NET version is under development).

If you need some modelling tool support then
[Power architect](http://code.google.com/p/power-architect/) can be used with [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/).

The problems associated with managing database schema upgrades are subtle. For some background reading I would recommend:

- [Evolutionary Database Design](http://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html)
- [Get your database under version control](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/02/get-your-database-under-version-control.html)

## Update

Create a file called **liquibase.properties** to hold the database details:

```
url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test
username=myuser
password=mypass
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
classpath=C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver\\sqljdbc_1.2\\enu\\sqljdbc.jar
changeLogFile=database-changelog.xml
```

When using liquibase against an existing database you can run the following commands:

```
liquibase generateChangeLog
liquibase changelogSync
```

The first command will create an XML file called **database-changelog.xml** containing the extracted data model.
The second command is optional, but useful if you want to apply new changes to the current database. It marks the extracted changesets as already executed in the database.

Now that you have a starting point, you can proceed to add new changesets to the **database-changelog.xml** file. To apply these new changes just run the following command:

```
liquibase update
```

This is the same command that you use for brand new databases. During an update operation liquibase will compare the changesets in the XML file to the changesets already applied to the target database.

For more advanced usecases I suggest reading the liquibase documentation and the following answer may also help:

- [comparing databases and genrating sql script using liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397488/comparing-databases-and-genrating-sql-script-using-liquibase/8408334#8408334)

Comment: @ Mark O'Connor : tnx +1. I read this articles already. Is it possibe to run some command line for Liquidbase to deploy my database from create script or do I need to create Liquidbase project manually etc.? Can I just load Liquidbase schema from sql create database file and then deploy? I just need to deploy changes, do not need other stuff like version control. Just need to apply changes and keep the data.