# liquibase: generate changeset from 2 databases

Tags: postgresql, diff, versioning, liquibase

How is it possible to use liquibase for comparing "original" database and "updated" one to generate the changeset from the differences (postgresql)?

I checked documentation and realized that there is no such feature listed. So perhaps I need to look at other tools?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397488/comparing-databases-and-genrating-sql-script-using-liquibase/8408334#8408334

Comment: How about relying on your source control system for a diff. Using a branch or a tag should allow you to see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any tool for this that outputs at least relatively good diff. There were some tools that were producing differences files, but the output was unacceptable.

You may want to read this post from liquibase blog.
[The Problem With Database Diffs](http://blog.liquibase.org/2007/06/the-problem-with-database-diffs.html)

Comment: Liquibase can also generate diffs between databases. It's a useful feature in order to capture changesets that might have occured without liquibase's knowledge

Comment: @MarkO'Connor This output sure can be used as a base. But it won't save you from possible problems (see link above for example of those).

Comment: I don't deny the issues with diffs. See the links I have in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746908/how-to-automate-deployment-of-changes-to-database/12752861#12752861