# Database deployment with MySQL and Capistrano

Tags: mysql, deployment, version-control, capistrano, liquibase

I've set up Capistrano and now use it for deploying to staging and live servers, which has been a great improvement to my devt workflow. What I am now wondering is how best to handle database deployment. I've had a Liquibase which looks good, but I'm not entirely sure what the best approach is yet. Should I be syncing data from live to staging and development servers so that they are proper clones of the live site? Also, would schema changes then generally be the type of thing which would be versioned and deployed to staging/live? Any pointers on best practice and what you guys do would be appreciated. I should add that I work with MySQL databases mostly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liquibase is not really designed to "sync" a production database with a development 
environment. Instead it's designed to track all changes to a dev environment, so that they can be faithfully reproduced on production.

Having said that liquibase does contain some powerful tools for extracting and comparing databases to each other. This functionality however is designed to support initializing a new project or discovering the missing "changeset" that could be added to an existing project in order to "sync" two databases.

The best way to discover liquibase is to try it out. For your purposes you'll be looking at the command-line implementation. (If you want to embed liquibase within Capistrano then all you'll need is the liquibase jar and the JDBC jar associated with your database.)

PS

The following is an example of comparing two databases in liquibase:

- [comparing databases and genrating sql script using liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397488/comparing-databases-and-genrating-sql-script-using-liquibase/8408334#8408334)