# Flyway manual script generation

Tags: flyway

We have a customer with a IT-department that insist on getting database updates as scripts prior to upgrades (they want to "read" the updates before implementing them).

Being an avid user of flyway it made me think about a way of generating a script from flyway based on updates and send this script to IT. This script would at the very least need to create version table if non-existant, check version and apply needed updates. It would of course be proprietary to database vendor (in my case Oracle).

This would allow us to run updates with flyway automatically in development environments and create manual scripts for test and production.

Are anyone aware of something like that having been contemplated or endeavored before? Would it be trivial or a momentous task?

Comment: Not really helpful, but I do know that Liquibase has this functionality. I'm not familiar with the flyway codebase, so I have no idea if it would be possible to do there. This question says it should be possible in flyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482644/can-flyway-or-liquibase-generate-an-update-script-instead-of-updating-the-databa?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this exact problem when I worked at a consultancy (Intelliware) so the devs there put together some code and pushed it up to GitHub.

We tried unsuccessfully to get it included into the Flyway core repo.

https://github.com/Intelliware/flyway-script-generator