# Postgresql create pg_dump for schema upgrade

Tags: postgresql

i have two postgres databases on different servers. Both have a 'public schema' with the same tables inside.
One of them is used for developing and I am creating new tables of new columns inside some tables.
How can i pg_dump the developing DB structure in order to get a sql that i run on the second DB to create the missing columns / tables (and constraints if possible)

Comment: So you want a dump as a diff, so it would only change the columns and other items that have changed? For that you need a third party library, for which you might get suggestions at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if it's possible with pg_dump.

However, you can use Liquibase. It's a database versioning tool which also allow to generate diff of given two databases.

Have a look at:

- [Liquibase Command Line create diff changelog in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943302/liquibase-command-line-create-diff-changelog-in-sql)
- http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html

Answer (score 0):

For this case exist few tool with same functional

http://pgdiff.sourceforge.net/

https://github.com/fordfrog/apgdiff

this is utilities full cover you requirements

and you can use this for make you own tool

pg-diff - python tool to diff to schemas
https://github.com/brendonh/schemup