# How to update table structures and stored procedures from Development to Production server in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have three PostgreSQL servers:

1. Development,
2. Practice
3. Production

The Production server has all the data of interest and is in heavy use. However, after many months of development, the Development server has some new tables and different table structures as well as new and changed stored procedures.

Is there a way of automating detection of which tables and stored procedures are different between the Development and Production servers so as to automate changing the Production server to match the new/changed tables and procedures from the Development server?  Or am I stuck going through this table by table and stored procedure by stored procedure manually?

Ofcourse, the goal is to retain the table data from the production server but with the tables and procedures of the development server.

Comment: Check out schema migration tools like Liquibase or Flyway. Do *not* try to "diff" the different instanced. Maintain proper migration scripts that are stored in a version control system. Never ever do changes to the model manually "on-the-fly"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name All new terms to me. Any suggested links that can show how to generate a change file with Liquibase between the development and production servers such that the production server can be changed to the new tables and stored procedures? Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24014467/4800355

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz Thanks. Any examples how to use the command-line of Liquibase with PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is short step by step tutorial for using liquibase with postgresql to generate database diff in sql format.

I assume you have java installed.

- download liquibase itself
- download latest version of postgresql jdbc driver from http://jdbc.postgresql.org and put it into liquibase home's lib directory
- run

`./liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver 
    --url=jdbc:postgresql://host1:port1/dbname1
    --username=user1 \
    --password=pass1 \
    diffChangelog \
    --referenceUrl=jdbc:postgresql://host2:port2/dbname2 \
    --referenceUsername=user2 \
    --referencePassword=pass2 > db-changelog.xml`

Here reference database is your where your changes are made.

- finally last step to get sql script run (against db at `host1:port1`):

`./liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver \
    --url=jdbc:postgresql://host1:port1/dbname1 \
    --username=user1 \
    --password=pass1 \
    --changeLogFile=db-changelog.xml \
    updateSql > changes.sql`

Before you apply genereated sql script onto production database you should clean it up - liquibase is introducing some metadata tables (`databasechangelog` and `databasechangeloglock`) - but thats simple search and delete.

That's it.

Final note is as @a_horse_with_no_name said: spend some time to learn how to put your db changes in `VCS` and avoid executing them manually (in favor of liquibase or flyway).

Comment: Granted. Had I known this several years ago when first moving from FoxPro to PostgreSQL, I certainly would have done so :). Now I'm stuck with two existing databases that need to be made into one...not fun. Thanks