# How to execute liquibase with java.lang.NumberFormatException on PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, powershell, liquibase

In trying to execute diffChangelog in liquibase 3.3.3 on a PostgreSQL 9.3 database (from PowerShell script) as:

```
$_cmd='C:\liquibase-3.3.3-bin\liquibase 
--driver=org.postgresql.Driver 
--url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/chaos 
--username=postgres --password=Password  
  diffChangelog
--referenceUrl=jdbc:postgresql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432/chaos
--referenceUsername=postgres --referencePassword=Password > db-changelog.xml';

CMD.EXE /c "`"$_cmd`""
```

I get the error:

```
*CMD.EXE : Unexpected error running Liquibase: 
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
For input string: "B'00000000'::"bit""*
```

I am using Java version 8 update 45. (The most current version).

The postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar is located in C:\liquibase-3.3.3-bin\lib\ directory.

The PostgreSQL version is 9.3.

Anybody know how to fix this error or make this work?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: If you `write-host $_cmd` and copy-paste the result into cmd prompt, does it work?

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace in order to see if this is a Liquibase problem or a problem with the driver?

Comment: @vonPryz (don't know how to paste into cmd prompt)  Coping output of write-host gives: exact same error as above with DatabaseException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: ... No difference. Ideas?  :-(

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What stacktrace? (I'm new to all this).  No stacktrace is apparent to me. (I'm a newb to this). Thanks.

Comment: If you can, try with the Java 7 VM. I think there are some issues with Liquibase and Java 8.

Comment: @SteveDonie Uninstalled Java 8, went to Java 7 Update 79 (64-bit) 118Mb version 7.0.790. Still same results. (Even went down to liquibase version 3.2.3 -- same results). Help please.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   After much study, I believe the problem is in the way PostgreSQL bytea datatype is being read. Any idea how to deal with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thanks to a_horse_with_no_name and Radek Postolowicz of 
[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487670/how-to-update-table-structures-and-stored-procedures-from-development-to-product) for pointing me in the right direction.

The problem was found in a PostgreSQL table that defined column qstatus as:

```
qstatus bit(8) DEFAULT B'00000000'::"bit"       <--**HERE IS THE PROBLEM!
```

**PostgreSQL bytea datatype is correctly interprested** by all parties.

Dropping this column solved all issues.

Further testing (for me) showed that any column defined with casting in someway fails with liquibase:

e.g.,

```
qstatus bit(8) DEFAULT B'00000000'::"bit"
```

or

```
cmi character varying(1) DEFAULT ' '::bpchar
```

Hope this helps.