# Does LiquiBase generate DDL for schema diff?

Tags: ddl, liquibase

Is there a way to generate DDL for schema differences, much like the Synch capability in TOAD?

Not certain how the "updateSQL" option is used? I am using the diff option for comparing schemas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [comparing databases and genrating sql script using liquibase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397488/comparing-databases-and-genrating-sql-script-using-liquibase)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with two steps:

1. Running diffChangeLog between two schemas will output a Liquibase changelog file describing what it will take to update one schema to match the other
2. If you run updateSQL passing the generated changeLog, Liquibase will output the SQL it will execute when running the changelog

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Would prefer an option to generate the DDL without the update - can that be done?

Comment: Using updateSQL in the above steps will generate the DDL without actually doing an update. It just outputs what would run.

Comment: I have the 'diffChangeLog' generate the XML file (say diff.xml). How can I apply it to generate the DDL using the command line liquibase.bat ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am able to generate the SQL with  liquibase.bat updateSQL. However, I get SEVERE 11/17/14 11:46 AM: liquibase: Unknown parameter: 'referenceDefaultSchemaN
ame'