# How to generate liquibase changelog xml for perticular table of database

Tags: mysql, liquibase

By using liquibase  we can generate changelog for whole database but I want to generate changelog for selected tables rather than whole database.

Have anyone idea about this?

Comment: Related to? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397488/comparing-databases-and-genrating-sql-script-using-liquibase  The "diffChangeLog" command will produce the schema changes between two versions of a database. Otherwise I simply copy-n-past the changesets I'm interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for it currently, but it is something I am planning on looking at today. Follow https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-875 for when the feature is available.