# Flyway diff tool

Tags: flyway

I found this [comparing databases and genrating sql script using liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397488/comparing-databases-and-genrating-sql-script-using-liquibase)

and I was wondering if how I can do the same with Flyway.
1.- Generating sql script from the differences between tow databases.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality to do this at this point.

Comment: Thanks very much. It would be nice to have such a thing in Flyway. I guess I would have to integrate both LiquiBase and Flyway in my project to automate some proceses.

Comment: @chemipot Making a database diff tool is a *very* large and complicated challenge. Not at all appropriate to *Flyway*. For me, the entire point of using *Flyway* is that I will *never need* a database diff tool. I always know the current state of each database by looking at the list of applied migrations.

Comment: Hi Axel, is it possible in 2019?

Comment: @BasilBourque the thing is that if you change your JPA entities, you should be able to get a ballpark idea of the changes in underlying schema, rather than manually figure them out.

Answer (score 10):

There is an option if you use IntelliJ IDEA. Install [JPA Buddy](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15075-jpa-buddy) and follow this video:

[image]

Comment: Currently it should be marked as the answer. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use any tool able to do database comparison and generate SQL: Oracle SQL Developer, TOAD, Squirrel SQL, etc.

Comment: that's true but what I need it is a build-in functionality with a Java APi to integrate with my project and automate a process and those are just Datasources clients that does not provide what I need. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase could make the diff from current database (e.g: product) and reference database (e.g: development), but unfortunately, it only works in the same database type, not cross databases with problems: [Java Hibernate, Liquibase supports cross databases and SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525671/java-hibernate-liquibase-supports-cross-databases-and-sqlite)