# Using liquibase versioning table definitions, not change sets

Tags: oracle, diff, sybase, liquibase, changeset

I'd like to have my version only the latest table definition in my repository, (no change sets), and have liquibase figure out which changes are needed when patching my databases. Please take note that I have a very big database schema (1000+ tables) installed in hundreds of customer sites, with different versions each one, and I really don't know which objects each version has

How can I make a liquibase-based installer for my application, given my set of table definitions, and hundreds of databases with about 12 different versions of objects on each one?

To be more specific, I'd like liquibase to compare my table definitions with the production database, and emit the alter table statements required to make the database current with my latest version.

I could contribute code if necessary in order to get this done

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase and tools like it (for example [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)) are primarily designed to support database migrations. A migration is where every change to the DB is tracked so that it can be replayed on target environments thereby keeping them in sync with development (although time-shifted). It's all about keeping your schema under revision control.

Your use case is a little different. If I understand correctly you're trying to retrofit Liquibase onto a series of environments that you are not 100% certain match your application's current schema?

I would only recommend migration tools like liquibase if you intend to use them going forwards. If all you want is a DB diff tool, I would suggest you look elsewhere.

To perform an initial sync then I would suggest you investigate the [diffLog](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html) command, coupled with [changeLogSync](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html) command to initialize liquibase on the target DB.

- [comparing databases and genrating sql script using liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397488/comparing-databases-and-genrating-sql-script-using-liquibase/8408334#8408334)